# C# Not steping out of do While loop when having two or conditions

Tags: c#

I have a simple menu method where you highlighting the options with the arrowkeys and then press ENTER or T to leave. However its not working when I have both conditions in the while loop. I need help to understand why. I want the program to leave the while loop when either ENTER OR T is pressed.

Things I tested:

- Works fine using only one of the conditions.
- Debugged and key gets the correct value (enter or t) depending on what I pressed.
- Using () on each condition

```cs
do
{
  key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

  switch (key)
  {
    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
    {
      if (currentSelection - 1 >= optionsPerColumn)
        currentSelection -= optionsPerColumn;

      break;
    }
    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
    {
      if (currentSelection - 1 + optionsPerColumn < diceMenuOptions.Length)
        currentSelection += optionsPerColumn;
      else if (optionsPerColumn < diceMenuOptions.Length)
        currentSelection = diceMenuOptions.Length;

      break;
    }
    case ConsoleKey.T:
    {
      if (canCancel)
        return -1;
      break;
    }
  }
} while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter || key != ConsoleKey.T); //This is not working

Console.CursorVisible = true;
return currentSelection;
```

Comment: `while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter || key != ConsoleKey.T);` Give us a _single_ example of a key that _won't_ meet that condition. You can't? That is why the code is wrong. Because it is equvalent to `while (true)`.

Comment: I always need two tries to make boolean logic right.  Due to the negation you should better try `key != ConsoleKey.Enter && key != ConsoleKey.T`

Comment: You may want to keep looping while the pressed key is not enter nor T. It's and AND not an OR

Comment: Thanks Manuel that works. Dont fully understand why though since I thought that would make it look for both values and not either one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are currently checking if the key is not `enter` or not `T`. This will not work since `enter` and `T` are two different keys and therefore one of the two conditions will always be `true`.

You need to change it to `while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter && key != ConsoleKey.T);`

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing both keys to leave the while. You just need to invert the logic. Try something like this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        
        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);


        } while  (key != ConsoleKey.Enter && key != ConsoleKey.T);
    }
```

Comment: You should have included a code example to improve the quality of this answer, its on the right track but as it stands much lower quality than the accepted answer.